# Can the word 'cos' mean because?

Tags: meaning

Am I right to understand 'Cos = Because?

A song has a string `'Cos I love you so...`.
This is "Because", correct?

Comment: *like, yeah* :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Because" is often shortened to **['cause](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%27cause)**, with an apostrophe.  It is pronounced 'coz' or 'cos'.  The shortened word has been around since the 15th century.

Comment: I would say that  both *'cause* and *'cos* (note the apostrophe) are acceptable as rather informal variants of *because*.

Comment: @tautophile https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/'cos

Answer (score 0):

**cos** conjunction  [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cos)

> ​it is not standard for 'because'

As in:

> You can cook dinner tonight cos I did it last night.

Literary/Music uses of words follow no rules (poetic license).  Use it as you may.